# Column value not allowed in SUBSTRING() as pos or len ? (error 1054 unknown column)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, substring, locate

I tried this query:

```
SELECT
    CHAR_LENGTH(
        '{start_123}'
    ) AS start_len,
    CHAR_LENGTH(
        '{end_123}'
    ) AS end_len,
    LOCATE(
        '{start_123}',
        text
    ) AS left_pos,
    LOCATE(
        '{end_123}',
        text
    ) AS right_pos,
    SUBSTRING(text, left_pos + start_len, right_pos - left_pos - end_len) AS text_part
FROM
    texts
WHERE
    id = 1
```

By that the readability would be much better instead of putting all the `LOCATE()` and `CHAR_LENGTH()` directly inside of `SUBSTRING()` and I thought it could be better not to calculate `left_pos` twice.

But it returns:

> [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'left_pos' in 'field list'

Isn't it allowed to use a column value in `SUBSTRING()`? Because this one results correct values:

```
SELECT
    CHAR_LENGTH(
        '{start_123}'
    ) AS start_len,
    CHAR_LENGTH(
        '{end_123}'
    ) AS end_len,
    LOCATE(
        '{start_123}',
        text
    ) AS left_pos,
    LOCATE(
        '{end_123}',
        text
    ) AS right_pos
FROM
    texts
WHERE
    id = 1
```

Comment: Correct.  You cannot use column aliases in the same `select ` (or `where`) where they are defined.  SQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in the `select`.  You need to repeat the expression or use a subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with `SUBSTRING()` *per se*.  You cannot use a column alias in the `SELECT` where it is defined.  SQL (in general) does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in the `SELECT`.  Similarly, SQL does not guarantee that the `SELECT` is evaluated before the `WHERE`, so aliases are also not allowed in the corresponding `WHERE`.

A subquery probably isn't so bad in this case:

```
SELECT t.*,
       SUBSTRING(text, left_pos + start_len, right_pos - left_pos - end_len) AS text_part
FROM (SELECT CHAR_LENGTH('{start_123}') AS start_len,
             CHAR_LENGTH('{end_123}') AS end_len,
             LOCATE('{start_123}', text) AS left_pos,
             LOCATE('{end_123}', text) AS right_pos
      FROM texts
      WHERE id = 1
     ) t
```